# Why I merge two dataframes and get an NaN column

Tags: python, pandas

What I'm doing is like:

```
df1['column1'] = df1.merge(df2, 
                          how = 'left', 
                          left_on = 'column2', 
                          right_on = 'column3')['column4']
```

I don't want to save the merge because there are too many columns in df2 and I don't want to manually drop them. But the problem is that this operation results in a lot of NaN in `df1['column1']`. I haven't figured out the reason, but I find that after I do the following change there will not be any NaN.

```
df1['column1'] = df1.merge(df2, 
                          how = 'left', 
                          left_on = 'column2', 
                          right_on = 'column3')['column4'].tolist()
```

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

You are using left join where entire left dataframe will be there and only the ones common with right dataframe will be added. The `NAN` is present because the key is matching in both the tables but other columns in that row contains blank values.

If you only want the common/intersection rows in both the dataframes, you should use `how = 'inner'` inside your `df1.merge()` function.